# Django not detecting changes in app model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have created an app called `base` and added a new model to it. However, whenever I run `python3 manage.py makemigrations base` It says `no changes detected`.

I have already added my in installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  ...
  'base.apps.BaseConfig',
  ...
]
```

And it does have the migrations folder inside the app containing and `__init__.py` file. I was wondering what is causing this issue.

This is my model:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

And my settings contains 4 files:

```
settings:
--__init__.py
-- dev.py
-- prod.py
-- staging.py
-- common.py
```

My `__init__.py`:

```
import os
from .common import *
from decouple import config

environment = config('DEV_ENV', cast=str)

if environment == "dev":
    from .dev import *
elif environment == "staging":
    from .staging import *
elif environment == "prod":
    from .prod import *
```

I have also already tried running

`python3 manage.py makemigration base --settings=project.settings.dev` and it still says
`no changes detected`

Comment: Can you share the contents of the migrations dir, have you checked the migrations table to see what migrations you have applied already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [**Abstract base classes** doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes),

> Abstract base classes are useful when you want to put some common information into a number of other models. You write your base class and put abstract=True in the Meta class. ***This model will then not be used to create any database table***. Instead, when it is used as a base class for other models, its fields will be added to those of the child class.

That is, if you remove `abstract = True` or set `abstract = False`, the Django will generate migration files for you!!!